# Does xUnit.net support overriding the names of individual rows of a Theory?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

In xUnit it is possible to have parameterized unit tests (theories).

E.g.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1,2)]
[InlineData(2,4)]
[InlineData(-1,-2)]
public void DoublingWorks(int a, int b)
{
    Assert.Equal(a+a,b);
}
```

However I can't see how override the name of the test, e.g. above I might like to make the name for the negative example "negative" to reflect it's different nature rather than being "DoublingWorks(a: -1, b: -2)". Is there a different type of attribute that I need to use to get this feature? Also can I selectively `Ignore` the test cases? Can I get it to work with the `MemberDataAttribute` too?

Comment: I seem to remember a github issue or two on this

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by overwriting the toString() Function .. but other than this, its not currently possible.

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/649

Here the github Link to the answer from the XUnit Developer